# Virtual layers w/ spatial query not working as before (3.18.1 vs 3.20.3)

Tags: qgis-3, sql, spatial-query, virtual-layer, st-union

I have a set of maps that intensively utilizes virtual layers, but last week our boss updated from QGis 3.10/3.18 to 3.20.3 in all PCs, and now the layers are not loading.

Normally they would refresh on startup and start showing my data automatically, but now they show as broken data links. When I reload the main layer, It shows properly; I think its because its a simple `SELECT` with a `where` statement.

But when I reload the layers that depend on spatial query (`ST_UNION`), they are calculated (I can see the data in their tables) but with no visible geometry. I did note that Geometry option changes automatically to `"Autodetect"` when opening the map in QGis 3.20.3 from it previous type `MultiPoligon`, but if I try to change it back and test the layer, it shows an alert saying `"Cannot find the specified geometry field!"` (it did not happen in QGis 3.10 or 3.18.1).

Already tried naming the calculated geometry with another name both in SQL and in Geometry options below, with no result. Giving it a CRS, though I didn't need it before, also doesn't fix the problem.

I don't know what else can I try, browsed some forums but didn't find anyone with this problem, and due to burocratic times, getting 3.18 back is not an easy option.

[image: Example 3.18.1]
[image: Example 3.20.3]

Comment: Is it okay that on the second image the Point was chosen as Geometry type, on the first image it is MultiPolygon? Can you try either the same or changing to the the *Autodetect*?

Comment: My mistake on the photo, I was doing that only to take the image and forgot to change it to multipolygon. Anyway, changing it to autodetect throws no error but the resulting layer has no geometry, but it has a field called geometry with a weird code in it

Comment: Can you please correct your question? And also can you please show the error to us? Did you try using your expression without an alias, with ` AS geom` and with `AS geometry`? Maybe using an alias for `"VIRTUAL_ORIGEN_PARCELAS" AS par` and then `par.geometry` can help, or it will is not sufficient for you?

Comment: tryed `SELECT par.ejido, par.circ, par.radio, par.mzna, par.cc, par.ten, par.registrado,
  RANK() OVER (ORDER BY CalcRegistrado(par.TEN,par.REGISTRADO)) AS color,
  st_buffer(st_union(par.geometry),0.05) AS geometry
FROM "VIRTUAL_ORIGEN_PARCELAS" as par
WHERE registrado IS NOT NULL AND registrado <> ''
GROUP BY par.circ, par.radio, par.cc, par.ten <> 'S', par.mzna, CalcRegistrado(par.ten,par.registrado)` but with no results

Comment: `VIRTUAL_ORIGEN_PARCELAS` seems to also be a virtual layer, have a look at its name/alias for the geometry column

Comment: Yes, it is another virtual layer. But as I said, this works fine in 3.18 and previous releases as it is :(

Comment: I dont know what to look for in its name/alias. What did you mean?